# MYSQL QUERY ACTING STRANGE

Tags: mysql, innodb

So I have this query

```
 SELECT COUNT(b.user_ticket_id) as tiketscount
 FROM event_tickets a
 INNER JOIN user_tickets b ON a.event_ticket_id = b.event_ticket_id
 WHERE b.status = 'used' AND a.event_id = '1'
```

which gave me expected result(which is count = 1) and i decided to try the code query below

```
 SELECT COUNT(b.user_ticket_id) as tiketscount
 FROM event_tickets a
 INNER JOIN user_tickets b ON a.event_ticket_id = b.event_ticket_id
 WHERE b.status = 'used' AND a.event_id = '1  DROP TABLE contact "1=1"'
```

and i got the same result as previous but when i change the one to 2 like below  , no results, is it possible mysql is using the first character it finds?

```
 SELECT COUNT(b.user_ticket_id) as tiketscount
 FROM event_tickets a
 INNER JOIN    user_tickets b ON a.event_ticket_id = b.event_ticket_id
 WHERE b.status = 'used' AND a.event_id = '2  DROP TABLE contact "1=1"'
```

Anyone knows why that is possible? Thanks

I am using MYSQL 5.5.30  InnoDB

Comment: I don't see a reason to be queries with string literal values like that, unless you were testing for SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  Here's a string value which might expose the vulnerability:  "`1' OR 1=1 --`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event_id is an number column type of some sort (maybe INT), so MySQL is converting your string `'1  DROP TABLE contact "1=1"'` to `1` making it identical to the first query.

In the third query it is also doing it's best to convert the value, and does the same, distilling the query down to:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.user_ticket_id) as tiketscount FROM event_tickets a INNER JOIN    user_tickets b ON a.event_ticket_id = b.event_ticket_id
WHERE b.status = 'used' AND a.event_id = 2
```

Which I would assume there are no records with an `event_id` of 2 and `status` of 'used'.

If your column is INT and not some form of text there is no need to enclose your numbers in quotes and it is actually discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, because MySQL is doing an implicit data conversion. MySQL is converting the supplied string literal into a numeric.

As a demonstration of what's happening, try these queries:

```
SELECT '123ABC  ' + 0
SELECT 'A1B2    ' + 0
SELECT '1.23D56 ' + 0
SELECT ' 78 90  ' + 0
```

What you will find is that MySQL is reading the string literal, and converting the value to a numeric value. It starts with leftmost character of the string, reading a character at a time (left to right) until it reaches the end of the string, or until it encounters a character that results in a string that can't be converted to a numeric value.

You can also try this same type of query with the string literals in your example,

```
 SELECT '1  DROP TABLE contact "1=1"' + 0 
 SELECT '2  DROP TABLE contact "1=1"' + 0
```

Those return numeric values of 1 and 2, respectively.

This behavior seems somewhat "strange", given that other databases (like Oracle and SQL Server) will throw errors when some of these same strings are converted to numeric. MySQL is more lenient, and assumes that any string value can be converted to numeric.

Comment: Thanks, makes so much sense, i am a msql person so i was surprised to see it return results. thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
mysql> create table foo (id int);
mysql> insert into foo (id) values (1), (2), (3);
mysql> select id from foo where id='2 DROP TABLE';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from foo where id='4 DROP TABLE';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from foo where id='0 DROP TABLE';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Since your `2 DROP TABLE ...` string starts with a number, MySQL is "politely" auto-converting it to an int to match against the id field. So basically the `1` or `2` is kept, and the rest of the string is simply thrown again.

Note that when I tested with `0` or `4` as the initial numbers, no rows were found, because there are no rows that have id `0` or `4` in the table.

Also note that MySQL is issuing warnings. The text for this case is:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                          |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '0 DROP TABLE' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

So yes, MySQL is simply truncating the string parts of your "number".

Comment: Thanks, i get it now, im coming from sqlserver so i was surprised

Comment: MySQL is very much more flexible and accepting of things. It has its good points and bad points. In some cases you probably DO want it to reject stuff, which you can do by forcing strict mode.